# Differentiate between buffer overflow and other errors when writing to a pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I am writing to a pipe, and getting a

`"Buffer overflow? : Resource temporarily unavailable"` error.

**I would like to differentiate between a buffer overflow error, and other pipe related errors.**

Here is the code I use for writing to the pipe:

```
void forward_data_asynch(int source_sock, int destination_sock) {
  char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
  int n;

  //put in error condition for -1, currently the socket is shutdown
  while ((n = recv(source_sock, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0)) > 0)// read data from input socket 
    { 
      send(destination_sock, buffer, n, 0); // send data to output socket
      if( write(pfds[1],buffer,n) < 0 )//send data to pipe
          perror("Buffer overflow? ");
    }

  shutdown(destination_sock, SHUT_RDWR); 
  close(destination_sock);

  shutdown(source_sock, SHUT_RDWR);
  close(source_sock);
}
```

The pipe has been set as non-blocking:

```
/**   Make file descriptor non blocking */
int setNonblocking(int fd)
{
  int flags;

  /* If they have O_NONBLOCK, use the Posix way to do it */
#if defined(O_NONBLOCK)
  /* Fixme: O_NONBLOCK is defined but broken on SunOS 4.1.x and AIX 3.2.5. */
  if (-1 == (flags = fcntl(fd, F_GETFL, 0)))
    flags = 0;
  return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
#else
  /* Otherwise, use the old way of doing it */
  flags = 1;
  return ioctl(fd, FIOBIO, &flags);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just check `errno`?

Comment: That's not what "buffer overflow" means.

Comment: If the output pipe is non-blocking, you'll get EAGAIN when you can't write your message to the pipe.  It isn't an error on the part of the system; it is the system telling your program to hold up — your program is working faster than its consumer process(es) can handle the data it is sending down the pipe.  The simplest fix is to make the pipe blocking, but there was presumably a reason for making it non-blocking.  Since it is non-blocking, you must devise a strategy to deal with EAGAIN — a better strategy than reporting an error.

Comment: Yes, it is non-blocking for a reason -  so after the failed write I will get EAGAIN in the errno (and I can add my logic there)